# How to cluster vectors from grouped data with each cluster having exactly one observation from each group?

Tags: r, algorithm, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a data set with 4 unique groups and 70 observations in each group, each observation being a numeric vector of size 4. I'm looking to make clusters of size 4, getting one observation from each group in the cluster while minimizing euclidean distances within clusters. It seems semi-related to the stable marriage problem, but it isn't quite the same with more groupings. If the problem could be solved with a greedy algorithm, that would be fine too.

There are some vectors that have the same values in the different groups, so those would be easy to classify together in a cluster with 1 representative from each group that are similar (as they are the same). The trouble comes when I have these leftover vectors that do not match, some of which are close and others which are not. I typically use R as I come from Statistical programming, but if there is an easier solution in python, that would be helpful as well. An example of how my data generally looks is the following:

```
myvec <- runif(400)
mat <- matrix(data = myvec, ncol = 4, nrow = 100)
groupings <- c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),25))
dat <- cbind(as.data.frame(mat), groupings)
names(dat) <- c("val1","val2","val3","val4","group")
head(dat)
```

Comment: In your example you create a groupings vector of 100 and `cbind` to a matrix of 25 rows so the matrix is repeated 4 times. That lets you create groups of 4 with 0 euclidean distance in each group. I assume that is not what you want. Perhaps you want `mat` to have 100 rows and 4 columns?

Comment: A starting point is to run the stable marriage algorithm three times. Given four groups labelled A,B,C,D. Run stable marriage to combine A and B into a single group with 70 pairs of observations. Then combine C and D. Finally, combine AB with CD.

Comment: Thanks, @user3386109. I'll start there and see where it leads me.